# Establish connection between R and Aspen Plus

Tags: r, matlab, aspen

I am trying to establish a connection between R and Aspen Plus (a chemical process simulator). I have succeeded in making the connection between MATLAB and Aspen Plus (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/69464-aspen-plus-matlab-link), but not with R.

I believe the problem is related to creating and invoking a COM server. I would like to be able to perform the same simulation as at https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/69464-aspen-plus-matlab-link, only using R instead of MATLAB

Comment: I also know that it is possible to establish the connection between Python and Aspen Plus using win32.Dispatch (http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/06/14/Running-Aspen-via-Python/). I would really like to be able to use R to do this

Comment: I have asked this same question to the Aspen Tech Suport Center. Here is there answer:

The Aspen Plus Windows user interface is an ActiveX Automation Server. The ActiveX technology (also called OLE Automation) enables an external Windows application to interact with Aspen Plus through a programming interface using a language such as Microsoft's Visual Basic. The server exposes objects through the COM object model. If the R programming language can interact with the COM interface, then it should work. Any ideas?